# C#: поле 32 в ISO8583

Tags: c#, iso

Столкнулся с ситуацией - при формировании сообщения 0800 неправильно формируется поле 32 (данные процессингового центра).
Поле переменной длинны, у меня имеет длину  6 символов из 11 возможных.

Т.е.
32 поле = "06" + "542996" (длинна +значение)
делаю как в примере в стандарте, по идее ошибки не должно быть, но имеено в этом поле и есть ошибка.

Детали расчета:

```
[0][6] = {0x30 0x36} = byte[] {48, 54}

[5][4][2][9][9][6] = {0x35 0x34 0x32 0x39 0x39 0x36} = byte[] {53, 52, 50, 57, 57, 54}
```

В итоге я эти два массива склеиваю и передаю в сообщение.

**Из-за ошибки в этом поле я не получаю ответа на все сообщение. В чем именно шибка я не понимаю, поэтому прошу разобраться.**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка?

Comment: Рекомендую написать подробно, что Вы делаете и что за ошибка у Вас выходит. Данный стандарт ISO может никто не знать, поэтому постарайтесь описать проблеме вне контекста ISO.

Comment: Из-за ошибки в этом поле я не получаю ответа на все сообщение. В чем именно шибка я не понимаю, поэтому прошу разобраться. Спасибо за замечание.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в ЗАГОЛОВКЕ сообщения, мой расчет был верен.

Comment: Может быть, напишете поподробнее об ошибке? Это может пригодиться другим в будущем.

Comment: В начало сообщения добавляется заголовок из 5и байтов, они выдаются Процессинговым Центром. Ошибка была в том что они мне дали неправильный заголовок (есть детальнее, вместо 0х99 надо было 0х97).